# Is there such a thing as indexing through type?

Tags: python, list

I'm not sure why this works and was wondering if it had to do with indexing a type.

```
z = ["first", 2, "third"]   

print(z[z[1]])
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, but the reason it works is because `z[1]` is `2` and `2` is a valid index for the list `z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have

```
z = ["first", 2, "third"]
```

that means

```
z[0] == "first"
z[1] == 2
z[2] == "third"
```

If you call `print` like this

```
print(z[z[1]])
```

We don't immediately know, what will be printed, because `z[z[1]]` is not in the list above. However, we know the inner part: `z[1]` which we can look up as `2`. That makes

```
z[z[1]] == z[2]
```

Now, we have `z[2]` which also is in the list above.

```
z[z[1]] == z[2] == "third"
```

We get `"third"` and that's what's going to get printed when you call `print(z[z[1]])`.